# Common "mouse over" background for controls with different "normal" backgrounds

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a number of controls (in this case, it's an Expander control, although I don't think it  bears any relevence) for which I want to have a slightly different shade of background in the "normal" state, but when the control is selected or in "mouse over" state, I'd like to set it to the common color.

Unless I misunderstand something, I'm running here into a dependency property precedence issue, namely:

- "Normal" background is set for each control
- "Mouse over" is set in the template

Thus, "Mouse over" has lower precedence and never gets applied.

Is there any way to set a common "mouse over" style without applying it to each control separately?

**EDIT**: Maybe a restatement of the question is whether I could do something like CSS's "!important'

Comment: You have to apply it to each control separately in their Style.

Comment: @Nitesh, Do you mean, apply the "IsMouseOver" trigger style to each control?

Comment: I mean each control type. So for example, a Button Style will have IsMouseOver trigger so this style will be applied to all Buttons in the app and same for other controls.